# Need expert's comment on fastest communication for .net application

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, communication

I am looking to achieve the fastest and scalable communication between several servers. I've developed a custom TCP socket server for this purpose with ([IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx)) as I think it would be the fastest communication in .NET, but I don't know if it crashes on high load, or if my solution is the fastest communication channel for .NET applications. Is there any open source solution out there to meet my needs?

**What's the fastest, scalable, reliable communication channel in .NET Applications?**

Comment: I have no idea if your "custom TCP socket server" is "the fastest communication channel for .net applications". I recommend you use a profiler to evaluate different options and pick the one with the best results.

Comment: so what's your suggestion? I've searched for (web services, .NET remoting) and at last i've picked custom TCP Socket

Comment: My web application requests for Index server is too high and it's chatty ? Im afraid the overhead of named pipes for creating a session in Network context affect the performance? whats your suggestion by the way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that a custom TCP or UDP server running a custom protocol that is ideally tailored for your particular needs would be the most efficient solution but since you're not really telling us much about WHAT you need to communicate it's rather difficult to answer.

Of course the solution also depends on what technologies you're comfortable with; writing scalable TCP servers is hard and you need to profile your solution at all stages of development with a realistic number of test clients and simulated data flow, etc. Writing custom reliable or semi reliable UDP protocols is even harder

It may well be that a 'less fast' solution will do and will be easier to implement as someone else will have done all of the hard work for  you. Again the only way to know is to profile something that resembles a realistic representation of your problem.

Comment: my context is on WAN or LAN but named pipes confine me to LAN and it has ack overhead which is not appropriate for the fast connection, My index server listen on a port and can accept connection only from one IP Address (web server) i need TCP server is multi-threaded cause there is huge request for index server (searching). im using the IOCP sample server of MSDN but i don't know if it crashes on high load it is it the fastest, scalable communication for .NET application

Comment: You could try using the free version of my IOCP server framework which you can get from here: http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000637.html This doesn't crash under load. You need to think about both ends of the communications; i.e. how you're writing your .net code to communicate with your server as well as how you're writing your server. How much data, how many connections, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many things that impact the performance of a network application, beginning with architectural design decisions, protocol choice, network congestion, down to message serialization, memory allocations, etc. There is no "one size fits all" way of network communication that makes an application automatically scalable, robust under high load, etc.

Lower level protocols have less overhead, that is right. But higher level protocols may be much better for some use cases, because they already provide some features which you otherwise would have to implement yourself. And, as I said, the protocol is not the only thing that affects the performance.

You need to gather your requirement, identify the bottlenecks, design an appropriate architecture, choose a protocol at the right abstraction level, and profile, profile, profile.